# Scraping selected columns from csv on Yahoo Finance using python

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, yahoo-finance

I'm trying to scrape selected columns from the Yahoo Finance data. I am able to scrape the entire data in csv format, but I'm curious to know how could I just scrape only selected columns rather than the entire csv data. I tried the split method to convert the string data into list and then accessing only the required columns from the list, but it doesn't work right.

```
import urllib2

listOfStocks = ["AAPL", "MSFT", "GOOG", "FB", "AMZN"]

urls = []

for company in listOfStocks:
    urls.append('http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=' + company + '&d=6&e=28&f=2015&g=m&a=11&b=12&c=1980&ignore=.csv')

Output_File = open('../Files_Directory/Yahoo_Finance/Historical_Prices.csv','w')

New_Format_Data = ''

for counter in range(0, len(urls)):

    Original_Data = urllib2.urlopen(urls[counter]).read()

    if counter == 0:
        New_Format_Data = "Company," + urllib2.urlopen(urls[counter]).readline()

    rows = Original_Data.splitlines(1)

    for row in range(1, len(rows)):

        New_Format_Data = New_Format_Data + listOfStocks[counter] + ',' + rows[row]

Output_File.write(New_Format_Data)
Output_File.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

It might make your life easier to just use one of the existing Yahoo Finance python modules, such as "[yahoo_finance](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yahoo-finance/1.2.1)"

Ex writing out just volume data using this module (not tested)

```
import yahoo_finance as yf
import csv

listOfStocks = ["AAPL", "MSFT", "GOOG", "FB", "AMZN"]

with open('my_output') as csvfile:
    Output_file = csv.writer(csvfile)

    for stock in listOfStocks:
        s = yf.Share(stock)
        hist = s.get_historical('2015-01-01', '2015-10-30')

        for row in hist:
            Output_file.writerow([stock, row['Date'], row['Volume'])
```